# Async Await with method calling external resource or returning local string

Tags: c#, async-await

I've always wondered if I'm doing async await correctly and I cannot find anything explaining my scenario and if the way I've coded my method(s) would affect my application.

I have a method that will call out to an external resource using a HttpClient if a local variable is not yet populated, if the local variable is defined I return the variable.

Here's an example:

```
1:  private static string foo;
2:  public static async Task<string> GetFooDataAsync()
3:  {
4:      var needToFetchFoo = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foo);
5:      if (needToFetchFoo)
6:      {
7:          var httpResponse = await myHttpClient.GetFooAsync(params);
8:          foo = httpResponse.data;
9:      }
10:     return foo;
11: }
```

My concern is on line 10 whereby I return the variable? Should I rather be doing something like?

```
return Task.FromResult(foo);
```

Does returning the variable without a Task.FromResult affect what async await is doing and cause issues higher up in my call stack?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Compiler will do the job for you.

Comment: The string foo you return gets wrapped inside a Task by the compiler. No need to use Task.FromResult

Comment: BTW you did **not** return the variable - only the value of the variable is returned (as a copy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have as is fine. When you use `async` the compiler has already implemented all the necessary plumbing to return a *task* through the *compiler generated* implementation of an `IAsyncStateMachine` .

As you can see in this nonsensical example [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRWQTwHYGNXIxJQC2yAPgAIAMABJQIwDcAsAFC2c30MB0AKgAtiAEwCW2AOasOXOowCsM9pQDM9AEy0AwrQDe7Tl3WUAHPQBsAHmAB7WwBsAfLQAitgMq2SEGIImSABQAlIZGBrJGRpQA7LREcBAyUQC+Ycb0ACy0ALIh+ulRbp7evv5SIbwA6lBiMCHJRmlsKUA=)

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    return true;
}
```

Translates *roughly* to

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<DoSomething>d__0))]
public Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    <DoSomething>d__0 stateMachine = default(<DoSomething>d__0);
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> <>t__builder = stateMachine.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

You would use `Task.FromResult` and `Task.FromException` when you haven't added the `async` keyword, and running synchronous code.

In these cases `Task.FromResult` is returning a *completed task* and `Task.FromException` will add the *exception* to the *Task* just as the framework would do for *exceptions* thrown in an `async` method

```
public Task<bool> DoSomeInterfaceAsync()
{
   try
   {
      // return a completed task
      return Task.FromResult(DoSomethingThatMightThrow());
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      // Add the exception to the task 
      return Task.FromException<bool>(e);
   }   
}
```

Also interesting to note in the compiler generated code shown above is the `MoveNext` method, which vindicates `Task.FromResult` and `Task.FromException`, and can be seen below with `SetException` and `SetException` respectively

```
private void MoveNext()
{
    bool result;
    try
    {
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
        return;
    }
    <>1__state = -2;
    <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
}
```

[AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asynctaskmethodbuilder.setexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Marks the task as failed and binds the specified exception to the
>   task.

[AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asynctaskmethodbuilder.setresult?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Marks the task as successfully completed.

Answer (score 2):

The caching logic is slightly flawed. During the time the http request is in progress, `foo` is left unpopulated, and if another method calls `GetFooDataAsync()` during this time, the http request will be repeated. Ideally the cache should populate only once.

To ensure one and only one invocation of the task, cache the task itself, not the result, and simply await it whenever you want to get the result. A second or third await won't invoke the method again, it'll simply access the existing result.

```
private static Task<string> foo = null;

private static async Task<string> GetFooDataAsync()
{
    async Task<string> GetFooDataInternal()
    {
        var response = await myHttpClient.GetFooAsync();
        return response.data;
    }

    if (foo == null) foo = GetFooDataInternal();
    return await foo;
}
```

Comment: Thank you John for point out the caching flaw. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have marked a method as `async` then you have to return the result, not the `Task` or `Task<T>`. The compiler will take care of the rest.

`Task.FromResult` is generally required when method is not marked as `async` but return type of method is `Task` or `Task<T>`.